# Access to the page body from selenium

Tags: selenium, phpunit

I want to create Selenium test that posts web form, but one field is riddle from the list. Riddle gets randomly. Answers are known. I should fill answer in field.

Is it possible to access in Selenium test to the page source code to define current riddle and place in the input field answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly. For example, in Ruby bindings it'd be `@browser.page_source`